# How ro remove extra characters in files names using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to remove an extra character `\` from multiple file names. Is there any way to do this ? Than in advance. Surprisingly when i type ls -l, I do not see backslash in the file names.

input

file1

```
asg19.mail14_+_\:38033421-38033567.mail
```

file2

```
asg19.mail14_+_\:38088821-38033567.mail
```

output

file1

```
asg19.mail14_+_:38033421-38033567.mail
```

file2

```
asg19.mail14_+_:38088821-38033567.mail
```

Comment: Do you want to rename the files or just modify a file containing these names ? Please post a sample input.

Comment: keep the  same name but just remove this extra black slash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) would be helpful here, but the following [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) snippet should work:

```
for file in *\\*; do
    mv "${file}" "${file/\\/_}"
done
```

You just need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

This code works for me for a file with name

```
asg19.mail14_+_\:38033421-38033567.mail
```

but you're saying that you don't see the backslash when doing `ls -l`, while I do see it.

Comment: how can run this on multiple files at same time ? sh script.sh filename* ?

Comment: This runs already on multiple files, all in the same directory though.

Comment: I think some how strangely this back slash hidden in the file name. When I try cat and the file name on the main terminal i see the back slash.

Comment: I think the `ls` command output is not standardized, so maybe we should not focus too much on that, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This will suppress all backslashes from the strings in file1, file2, ...:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
for file in file1 file2
do
    awk '{gsub("\\\\","");print}' $file > $tmp
    cat $tmp > $file
done
```

Comment: This suppresses backslashes inside the file, but the question is about filenames.

Comment: but I have thousands of files. :(

Comment: Please explain what makes you conclude there are backslashes in your file names. Also please tell what OS and what file system you are using.

Comment: when I try to see the contents inside the file, i run cat command and the file looks like it has backslash inside the name. but when i try ls -l, i do not see it. I am using linux X 64 server.

Comment: Please clarify "I run cat command and the file looks like it has a backslash inside the name". Is the file stored on a remote file server or a Windows file system ? The colon ':' might be invalid there.